# When did Tasslehoff recover the time traveling device that Raistlin took from Gnimsh?

Tags: dragonlance

In *War of the Twins* book 3 chapter 11, Raistlin gets the device/pendant from Gnimsh just before he kills him.

In chapter 13 Tasslehoff already has the magical device again:

> “But, now”—the kender glanced around—“the first thing to do is find Caramon and tell him I’ve got the magical device and we can go home.

I couldn’t find in the book how he gets it back.  Did he steal from Raistlin during his their conversation in the cell? It seems strange that Raistlin didn’t disassemble/destroy the device again knowing that the device was the cause of the explosion of the Portal in Zhaman.

Comment: Taş probably "borrowed" the time travel device from Raistlin and was sure he had returned it, until he found it in one of his pouches....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it doesn’t explicitly say he took it back. But at the beginning of chapter 13, Rasitlin is in a state of shock over what Tasslehoff has told him. He is sitting right next  to him with his hand on his shoulder. So that was probably the moment Tasslehoff got the device back. It was opportune because Raistlin wasn’t aware of his surroundings for a few moments.

Comment: Also, things tend to 'find their way' into his pockets without conscious effort. Conveniently, they tend to be either pretty precious or extremely useful to him

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. it is possible that Tasslehoff made “lift” to get the devices off of Rastlin, but Rastlin talks about the device afterwards as if he never had it. It’s a mistake.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include a direct quote of the dialogue you referred to.